# Short story from 70s with alien parasites that enhance nervous system

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to locate a story I read sometime in the seventies in an anthology so it may have been written earlier. A plague/alien parasite has infected earth wreaking havoc. It's communicated by touch (and those infected develop a compulsion to touch other people). Those people infect have grey skin caused by, it turns out, massive nerve growth.

The protagonist might have been a priest ministering to the "sick". And in the advanced stage the infected might have grown a third eye. It's also possible the infected were called "feelies" (but using this to search only turns up stories where feelies are a future version of tactile TV).

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: @Moonglow I'm pretty sure Eike is correct, the answer to the linked question is the one you're looking for.

Comment: While the answer is the same, I don't think the question is -- I in fact didn't recognize the story I was looking for in the earlier question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is Walter Millers "[Dark Benediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Benediction_%28story%29)". The protagonist ist not a priest, but at one point he takes refuge in a place where priests tend to people who have acquired the alien "neuroderm" parasite (which is mistaken for a plague but turns out to be a good thing in the end - the protagonist infects himself voluntarily after falling in love with (not a "feelie" but a) "dermie" (i.e. somebody carrying the neuroderm  symbiote)).

Comment: Also I just realised that I have answered this before: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41103/title-of-novelete-where-human-race-divided-into-those-with-skin-symbiote-and-tho/41104#41104